# Link to external Url and open modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to link to a contact form on another site but it's contained in a modal window.  This is pretty much what I'm trying to do [Linking Directly To An Open Modal Window Through a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971131/linking-directly-to-an-open-modal-window-through-a-url) however, the modal i'm trying to open does not have an id, just a class.  The class is

```
.modal-content
```

Is this a possibility without the modal having an id?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('.modal-content') != -1) {
    $('.modal-content').modal('show');
  }

});
```

Comment: Use the same approach as your example, just make sure to show the modal by targeting by class  $('.modal-content').modal('show'); Please post more code if you wanted more specific suggestions.

Comment: i added the exact code i've used and haven't had any luck

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule (and for good reason) when you redirect someone you don't and shouldn't have control over what their site displays.  Your only bet would be to see if the host site already has this capability, and route to that URL.

Your app not having control over someone else's app is very important to web security.